# Here Fleet Telematics admin area

Tags: here-api

I am using fleet telematics and accessing tile for kuwait. If a place is present into two tiles I combine  combine all coordinates from all rows for that place and convert that coordinates into polygon.

Please see the image below as i see weird polygons.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the end result you are expecting? Are you using the Admin area Advanced Data Set to display the city bounds of Kuwait?

Comment: https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?layer=ADMIN_POLY_9&level=11

Comment: This means that:

LAT “5246282,,1,1,1”
LON “960310,30,24,13,10"
is like that:

LAT “52.46282,52.46282,52.46283,52.46284,52.46285”
LON “9.60310,9.60340,9.60364,9.60377,9.60387"

Comment: Don't know what Admin level you need, but if more detailed than ADMIN_POLY_8 , try layer PSTLCB_GEN with level 12 (postal polygons).

Comment: When I add it it doesn't show anything in my region

Answer (score 1):

To get the city bounds of Kuwait city admin area, you may want to use ADMIN_POLY_8.
If you query that layer, you will notice that the ADMIN_LEVEL attribute here is '4' which corresponds to city.

To understand which layer to pick, check the description of the layer on sending this call

```
https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/doc/layer.json?layer=ADMIN_POLY_8&apiKey={{RESTapiKey}}
```

In the response, you will see the attribute 'ADMIN_LEVEL' which says 
'Administrative level 1 - 9.
To look up the country specific name/meaning, applications can load the static table {COUNTRY} and fetch the value from column'

When you query the static layer 'COUNTRY' , you will see that 'ADMIN_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION_4' corresponds to city.
This is how you can find out which layer to choose.

you have selected ADMIN_POLY_9 which has places with ADMIN_LEVEL 5.
This gives you the geometric bounds of SETTLEMENT within the city and thus the multiple polygons.

[image]

Comment: Then Why there are self intersecting polygons